# Recursive implementation of merge sort

Tags: optimization, c, recursion, mergesort

**Information about my code:**

I am following this [MIT OCW algorithms course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/). The first lecture described insertion sort and merge sort. I implemented merge sort in C.

The algorithm is structured as a function called from the `main` function. The array to be sorted is allocated dynamically in the `main` function but can also be statically allocated.

**What I am looking for:**

I am looking whether the 2 functions can be optimized without changing the algorithm(merge sort), whether it follows the best-practices of programming in C and does it have proper readability factor?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define SORTING_ALGO_CALL merge_sort

void merge_parts(int arr[], int length)
{
    /*
    Sorts into increasing order
    For decreasing order change the comparison in for-loop
    */
    int ans[length];
    //This for and next if-else puts the merged array into temporary array ans
    //in a sorted manner
    int i, k;
    int temp, j = temp = length/2;
    for (i = k = 0; (i < temp && j < length); k++){
        ans[k] = (arr[i] < arr[j]) ? arr[i++] : arr[j++];
    }

    if(i >= temp){
        while(j < length){
            ans[k++] = arr[j++];
        }
    }
    else{
        while(i < temp){
            ans[k++] = arr[i++];
        }
    }

    //This for-loop puts array ans into original array arr
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        arr[i] = ans[i];
    }
}

void merge_sort(int arr[], int length)
{
    if(length > 1)
    {
        merge_sort(&arr[0], (length/2));
        merge_sort(&arr[length/2], (length - length/2));
        merge_parts(arr, length);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int length;
    scanf("%d", &length);
    while (length < 1)
    {
        printf("\nYou entered length = %d\n", length);
        printf("\nEnter a positive length: ");
        scanf("%d", &length);
    }

    int *arr;
    if ((arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * length)) == NULL)
    {
        perror("The following error occurred");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    SORTING_ALGO_CALL(arr, length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

The book I am reading is *Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition* by Cormen. It mentions a sentinel value be placed at the end of two subarrays. That, if implemented, it can result in better efficiency. But I am not sure what to use as a sentinel value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've slightly reorganised your code to make it easier to follow.

```
void merge_parts(int arr[], int length)
{
    /*
    Sorts into increasing order
    For decreasing order change the comparison in for-loop
    */
    int ans[length];
    //This for and next if-else puts the merged array into temporary array ans
    //in a sorted manner
    int mid = length/2;
    int i = 0, k = 0, j = mid;
    while (i < mid && j < length){
        ans[k++] = (arr[i] < arr[j]) ? arr[i++] : arr[j++];
    }

    // Only one of the two loops will apply
    while(j < length){
        ans[k++] = arr[j++];
    }
    while(i < mid){
        ans[k++] = arr[i++];
    }

    //This for-loop puts array ans into original array arr
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        arr[i] = ans[i];
    }
}

void merge_sort(int arr[], int length)
{
    if(length > 1)
    {
        int mid = length/2;
        merge_sort(arr,     mid);
        merge_sort(arr+mid, length - mid);
        merge_parts(arr, length);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int length;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a positive length: ");
        scanf("%d", &length);
        printf("\nYou entered length = %d\n", length);
        if (length>=1) break;
    }

    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
    if (!arr)
    {
        perror("The following error occurred");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    merge_sort(arr, length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Then for the only optimisation I can think of, you could avoid some copying : when `j < length` after the main loop, it corresponds to a situation where the end of `arr` is already sorted in the right place. Thus, you don't need to copy it from `arr` to `ans` and then from `ans` to `arr`.

```
int mid = length/2;
int i = 0, k = 0, j = mid;
while (i < mid && j < length){
    ans[k++] = (arr[i] < arr[j]) ? arr[i++] : arr[j++];
}

while(i < mid){
    ans[k++] = arr[i++];
}

//This for-loop puts array ans into original array arr
for(i = 0; i < j; i++){
    arr[i] = ans[i];
}
```