# Binary Search in C - Optimization

Tags: optimization, c, performance

I know that there is a function `bsearch` present in `stdlib.h` but still I want to implement this.

This is my code for binary search. Any and all reviews are welcome.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

int bin_search(int arr[], int min_index, int max_index, int element)
{
    /*
    Searches for an element in the array arr
    Returns fist index of element if present else returns -1
    */
    if (min_index > max_index){
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        //Don't change this assignment of mid_point. It avoids overflow
        int mid_point = min_index + (max_index - min_index)/2;

        if (arr[mid_point] > element){
            return bin_search(arr, min_index, mid_point - 1, element);
        }
        else if (arr[mid_point] < element){
            return bin_search(arr, mid_point + 1, max_index, element);
        }
        else{
            return mid_point;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int length;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter a positive length: ");
        scanf("%d", &length);
        if (length > 1){
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("You entered length = %d\n\n", length);
        }
    }

    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
    if (arr == NULL)
    {
        perror("The following error occurred");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    int element;
    printf("\nEnter the element to be searched: ");
    scanf("%d", &element);

    qsort(arr, length, sizeof(int), compare);
    int index = bin_search(arr, 0, length - 1, element);

    if (index == -1){
        printf("\nElement not in the array");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nIndex of element is %d", index);
    }

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any discussion regarding this question can be done in this [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9579/discussion-between-aseem-bansal-and-josay). @codesparkle Just leave this comment if you want to delete all others

Comment: Why make `element` a `const` and not `min` and `max`?  Such `const` markup on parameters passed by value does no harm but is not part of the function's interface - in other words the caller does not care. From an interface point of view, `const` only has meaning for pointers, such as `arr`. It could be considered to have some utility in telling the reader that the call parameters remain unchanged (but personally I rarely, if ever, use it for parameters passed by value).

Comment: @WilliamMorris I am still confused about what is the best way to use `const`. I commented on ruds' answer about this confusion as he added 1 more `const` here. Perhaps you can answer my comments there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions says it "Returns fist index of element if present".  If I give it the numbers 2, 2, 2 and ask it to find 2 it says the 1, but the first index with value 2 is clearly 0.

Some minor comments on the code:

- the `arr` parameter to `bin_search` should be `const`.  This tells the compiler and the reader that the array is not changed by the function.  The compiler will then enforce this if you, by mistake, try to modify the array data.  The reader/user knows that her data is unchanged after the call.
- the parameter names `min_index` and `max_index` could be shortened to `min` and `max`.  Giving names an appropriate size is a service to the reader (auto-completion by the IDE is a service to you).  In general, the shorter the names, the less dense the code and the easier it is to read.  This can be taken too far of course, once names become meaningless.
- Note that it would be more normal to pass the start of the array and its size instead of the array plus two offsets.
- functions could be static.  This is of no significance in a one-file program but becomes important with bigger programs.  Making functions and global variables static restricts their scope to the file which allows extra optimisation and reduces namespace pollution.
- the output message needs a trailing \n
- there is no prompt for the input values - ok that is trivial. Personally I find this sort of test better with values entered on the command line.
- exit status is normally 1 (EXIT_FAILURE) on failure, not -1.  On success it is 0 (EXIT_SUCCESS).  These are UNIX conventions.

---

**EDIT**

You questioned the use of `const`. Its utility when used on parameters passed by
reference - pointers/array passed into functions - is, I think clear.

However, its use with parameters passed by value is not so clear.  It plays no
part in the interface seen by callers of a function, as it can have no
influence on the caller.  You can declare a function prototype in a public
header like this

```
int bin_search(const int arr[], int min, int max, int element);
```

and then define the function implementation like this:

```
int bin_search(const int arr[], const int min, const int max, const int element) {...}
```

And the compiler will be quite happy with the difference.

So it is purely an implementation issue.  Hence you should definitely **not** use `const` on pass-by-value parameters in public prototypes, only in the implementation (if at all).  Used in the implementation, `const` tells the reader and the compiler
that a parameter is not (and cannot be) changed.  This gives the reader some
extra information and of course the compiler will enforce this read-only
behaviour.

So shouldn't you use it on all parameters that are not changed (and some might say that parameters should never be changed)?  Good question!  I never use `const` on call parameters but would have no hesitation in adding `const` to a local variable

```
int cirle_area(double radius)
{
    const double pi = 3.14;
    return pi * radius * radius;
}
```

A lot of good programming style concerns consistency, so my inconsistency here
is troubling.  And my previous comment - that if you make the `element`
parameter `const`, then you should be consistent and do the same for `min` and
`max` uses consistency as an argument!

I'm afraid I can do no better than that.  I've programmed for 20 years in C
and have rarely seen `const` applied to parameters. But maybe it should be.

Comment: I'll take care of the incorrect comment. About `arr` being `const` why? I used `min` and `max` but `max` is defined in C++ and the IDE that I use(Code:blocks) starts to highlight it as a keyword so I thought to change them. It has auto-completion so length of variables isn't a problem. Any particular reason why I should use `static` functions? Can you tell me what it is this called so I can read up a bit(like `static` for variables is `storage class`)? About exit status, is that a convention or what?

Comment: So `const` should be used whenever I am passing pointers but not changing the contents. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Asked a [question on programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/204500/when-and-for-what-purposes-should-the-const-keyword-be-used-in-c-for-variables) about use of the `const` keyword. Please give your comments and suggest improvements.

Comment: Signaling the array as const is a good idea, for the other parameters const it's meaningless and just bloats the code. As for the the identifiers, I would argue that max_index is better than just max. A good rule of thumb (that do not work for every case) is to have a noun in the mix.

Answer (score 3):

If your average case is that the looked-for element is distributed uniformly randomly (and that your array is pulled from the same distribution), you actually gain in the average case by not returning early if arr[mid] == element.

---

William Morris's comment about `static` was most likely meant to apply to your `compare` helper function; presumably `bin_search` will be declared in a header file to be included in other translation units, in which case it must not be declared `static`.

---

Combining these comments:

```
int bin_search(const int arr[], int min, int max, const int element)
{
    /*
    Searches for an element in the array arr
    Returns index of element if present else returns -1
    */
    if (min >= max) {
        return arr[max] == element ? max : -1;
    }

    //Don't change this assignment of mid. It avoids overflow
    const int mid = min + (max - min) / 2;

    if (arr[mid] < element) {
        return bin_search(arr, mid + 1, max, element);
    } else {
        return bin_search(arr, min, mid, element);
}
```

This has exactly 2 * lg(N) + 1 comparisons (2 for each halving of the size, plus 1 on the final return). Your version has worst-case 3 * lg(N) comparisons and is worse in the average case (2.5 average comparisons per layer, saving on average (N-1)*2^-N + (N-2)*2^(N-1) + ... + 1*2^-1 layers, means that you get about 2.5 * (lg(N)-2) comparisons on average).

Comment: My solution has the downside that it accesses uninitialized memory when `max` < 0 initially, which may happen e.g. when code doesn't check for an empty array before calling `bin_search`

Comment: Any function that needs to called in other files by including the header files shouldn't be `static`. But these functions can access the `static` functions from the files from which they are called. Am I correct? As an example of what I think you have said, in this [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28224/recursive-implementation-of-merge-sort-optimization) the `merge_parts` function should be `static` but the `merge_sort` shouldn't be. Declaring `merge_parts` as `static` won't effect the use of `merge_sort` in another file. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: About declaring `mid` and `element` as `const`, should any variable, that isn't changed in the called function, be decalred `const`? I understand that declaring `arr` as `const` is relevant because it is a pointer that can be changed but the calling function's original value passed to the variable `element` cannot be effected here. Is this declaration of `const` for the purposes of clarity and perhaps a security measure in the scope of the called function?

Comment: Your code is missing a brace after the last else and shouldn't it be `2 * lg(N) + 2`. In the final case there are 2 comparisons, 1 for the `if` and 1 inside it.

Comment: After some thinking I think I might have found the best of both worlds. I'll update with a code that uses the same number of comparisons as you have suggested while still taking care of accessing uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 0):

Update `bin_search` with a best-case scenario **O(1)**, if the array has only 1 element.

```
int bin_search (int arr[], int min_index, int max_index, int element)
{
    // this is the best case scenario
     if(min_index == max_index)
     {
         if(arr[min_index] == element) 
            return min_index;
         else 
            return -1;
     }
     if (min_index > max_index)
     {
            return -1;
     }
     else
     {      
             int mid_index = (min_index + max_index) / 2;
             if (arr[mid_index] > element)
             {
                    return bin_search(arr, min_index, mid_index - 1, element);
             }
             else if (arr[mid_index] < element)
             {
                    return bin_search(arr, mid_index + 1, max_index, element);
             }
             else
             { 
                    return mid_index;
             }
    }
}
```

There is also an iterative process.

```
int bin_search (const int arr[], int min, int max, int element)
{
     int high = max+1;
     int low = min;
     while(low < (high-1))
     {
         int mid = (low + high)/2;
         if(element < arr[mid])
            high = mid;
         else
            low = mid;
     }
     if(arr[low] == element)
        return low;
     else
        return -1; // not found
}
```

Comment: The complexity doesn't change a bit but performance suffers in this code. My implementation is tail-recursive so there shouldn't be much overhead for function calls.

Comment: @AseemBansal: Note, "tail-recursive" is still "recursive" -- and by default still has any other recursion's performance issues.  You don't gain anything from it performancewise unless the compiler does tail-call optimizations (which it's not required to do).

Comment: @cHao What about gcc? I use Code:blocks IDE with gcc compiler.

Comment: @AseemBansal: Looks like if you compile with `-O2`, `-O3`, or `-Os`, or add `-foptimize-sibling-calls` to the command line, it should at least try.  At that point, the result depends on how good the detection is.

Comment: @AseemBansal and why my code is not "tail-recursive"?

Comment: @tintinmj I didn't imply that your code isn't tail-recursive. I just think that these changes are unnecessary **because** the code is recursive. If `n = 1` then your code will take 2 comparisons to get the answer while mine will take at most 4 comparisons. That is an improvement of `2 comparisons` for this case. In all other cases as the code is recursive it adds `log n` more comparisons. As it is `log base 2 of n` so even for `n = 8` the number of extra comparisons introduced by the changes outweigh the benefit introduced already. That's why I said that performance suffers.

Comment: @AseemBansal your code can also have two comparisons just add `if (arr[mid] == element) return mid;` after first `else`.

Comment: @tintinmj Same problem. It will add `log(base 2) n` comparison for all other cases except the base case.